# Do we ever find out what happened to Dr. Giger or The Cellular Regeneration and Entertainment Chamber after the DS9 episode "In the Cards?"

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-dominion, immortality

DS9 "In the Cards":

> **GIGER**: Doctor Bathkin of Andros Three was the first to come up with
>   the answer to solving the puzzle of death. Keep the cells energised.
>   Keep them in the game by teaching them new mitochondrial tricks.
>   Unfortunately, before he could finish his work, Doctor Bathkin died in
>   a shuttle accident. Or so they say. And while the soulless minions of
>   orthodoxy refuse to follow up on his important research, I could hear
>   the clarion call of destiny ringing in my ears. And now, after fifteen
>   years of tireless effort, after being laughed at and hounded out of
>   the halls of the scientific establishment, after begging and
>   scrounging for materials across half the galaxy, I have nearly
>   completed work on this. **The Cellular Regeneration and Entertainment
>   Chamber.**

At the end of the episode:

> WEYOUN: Really? I have a background in, shall we say, creative
>   genetics. I'd be most interested in hearing your theories.
>
> GIGER: Well, it may take some time to explain. Let me ask you a simple
>   question. Do you want to die?

Dr. Giger was on DS9 developing technology to make himself immortal. He enlisted the help of Jake and Nog to gain supplies for his project. Ultimately Weyoun and a couple of Jem'hadar transport Giger on their vessel. The episode ends with the conversation above and subsequently Weyoun trying out the chamber.

I am curious to know if Giger ever go the chamber to fully work, did the doctor stay with the Dominion, did Weyon help Giger in any way, etc.

Do we ever learn anything after this episode in-canon, writers notes, EU, or otherwise about Dr. Giger or The Cellular Regeneration and Entertainment
 Chamber?

Comment: nope... there's only a [Memory Alpha entry](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Elias_Giger)

Comment: Omegacron's answer to this question seems pretty comprehensive. Is there anything additional you think that he should address before offering an acceptance?

Comment: @Richard Sorry these past couple months have been difficult. I've been watching ST, posting questions, etc. to get my mind off of things. But my mind is in another place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No, neither Elias Giger nor his project are mentioned again in any episode, novel, or other licensed work after DS9 S05E25.**

The fact that we never hear of Giger again is actually quite telling - had it worked, a device which could render one effectively immortal would be a major commodity. Therefore, we can speculate that [Giger](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Elias_Giger) was not able to get the device functioning despite the Dominion's assistance. In fact, the episode was ambiguous as to whether or not the technology was even viable to begin with.

The [Weyoun](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Weyoun) that showed interest in the device - Weyoun 5 - was killed during a transporter accident two years later. Given that the Founders have no need for a regenerative device, it's entirely likely that Giger's research (and therefore, Giger himself) were abandoned without results.

Therefore, the last we see of Dr. Giger & his device is when they're transported aboard Weyoun's vessel at the end of "[In the Cards](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/In_the_Cards_(episode))".

[image]

Comment: Worth adding that Giger (and his device) do not appear in any further Trek novel, nor to my knowledge is he referenced in any of the DS9 comics, Ongoing comics or other licensed Trek property